# CRC calculating and BCH encoding [THEORY]

Tags: signal-processing, communication, crc32, telecommunication, cyclic

I have question about BCH Encoding. Is BCH Encoding is the same operation like CRC remainder calculation? M(x) mod G(x) = R(x) and R(x) is my BCH code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much correct.  To be precise, if your generator polynomial is **g(x)** and your block size is **n**, then the valid code words are the multiples of **g(x)** with **degree < n**.

Lets say you have a message **m(x)** of **degree < k**, and **g(x)** has **degree n-k**:  There are different ways you could turn your message into a unique valid code word.  **m(x)*g(x)** works fine, for example...  But we commonly want the code word to start with our actual message, followed by some check bits. In that case, the code word is:

**m(x)*x^(n-k) - ( m(x)*x^(n-k) mod g(x) )**

*Most* CRC checks are calculated in exactly this way as well, since CRC codes and BCH codes are both polynomial codes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_code).  They just have different generator polynomials.